# how to Qt QML application ihgh ram usage how to reduce

Tags: qt, qml

With qml stackview, the ram usage of the 5-page application increases to around 1500mb...
How can I free unused pages and images from memory?
how can i speed up my app

Comment: You probably have to provide [mcve]

Comment: What Qt version? Does it happen also when you set the software renderer instead of GPU renderer? Btw. I have experienced similar problems in the past very often. In the most recent versions, this was improved a bit but still the memory consumption is huge (when comapred to QtWidgets app) especially when you resize the window by mouse. Memory consumption, poor performance (especially on some computers with Windows) and ugly rendering artefacts around window edges was absolute "no go" factor for me to use QtQuick/QML. I still prefer using QtWidgets. QtQuick/QML is just broken.